# Cross-join issue in SQL statement (SAS)

Tags: sql, sas, cross-join

Can anyone please explain to me why this insists on doing a Cartesian product on the join?  To me it would seem logical for it to use the index.  Is there a way to force it to use the index (you can see I've tried but it's ignoring my `idxname` statement).

The below example is the simplest way I could reproduce the problem I am having and is not my actual code.

Create some test data:

```
data all_periods;
  do date=mdy(1,1,2015) to mdy(4,1,2015);
    do hour=0 to 23;
      do minute=0 to 59; 
        period_start = dhms(date,hour,minute,0);
        output;
      end;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Create an index on the test data:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create index period_start on all_periods;
quit;
```

Perform a self-join:

```
proc sql noprint _method;
  create table concurrent as 
  select a.period_start,
         count(*) as result
  from all_periods a
  join all_periods (idxname=period_start) b on b.period_start lt a.period_start
  group by 1
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-equijoins often don't use indexes.  I would actually recommend that you do this in a data step, using `retain`.  However, you might try this version in `proc sql`:

```
select a.period_start,
       (select count(*)
        from all_periods b
        where b.period_start < a.period_start
       ) as result
from all_periods a;
```

Most databases have cumulative sums built-in using window functions.  However, SAS does not support those natively.  So, `proc sql` is not the best way to do this calculation.

Comment: Yep, this.  Obviously if your actual code is doing something totally different, you either have to rethink this or post something closer to your actual code; but in general this is why SAS data step is awesome: it's natively able to do this stuff that SQL has a harder time with (ANSI, anyway).

Comment: Thanks, it certainly answered my main question which was should I be doing this in SQL or not.  I probably will post a follow up question soon with an exact example of what I was trying to do (because SQL would be so much simpler than a datastep) but I need to get some results out the door first.

Comment: @joe . . . This is definitely not an example where ANSI SQL falls short.  ANSI SQL supports cumulative sums, just not all database implementations (such as `proc sql`) support that part of the standard.  My intention is not to start a discussion on the merits of one versus the other, but SQL is also awesome.  One reason is that it is natively parallel and can take advantage of much more hardware that base SAS.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Fair enough.  They're both awesome in their own way. :)  I wasn't particularly intending to compare SAS to SQL - but 'base SAS' to 'proc SQL' - as inside of SAS, there are definitely places one is superior to the other.